# DataTable plugin, error during JSON parsing

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, datatables

I'm building a nested table with DataTable.

The table is built from a JSON string str that I get from an Ajax call.

**str** before JSON.parse:

```
"[ {\r\n  \"ente\" : \"Roma\",\r\n  \"cup\" : \"ABCDE3593CXXE\",\r\n  \"decretoImpegno\" : \"decreto singolo\",\r\n  \"dataDecretoImpegno\" : 61415276400000,\r\n  \"importoImpegno\" : 56000,\r\n  \"finanziatoMiur\" : 343434,\r\n  \"importoPagato\" : 55656,\r\n  \"importoInPagamento\" : 9999,\r\n  \"details\" : [ {\r\n    \"progressivoPagamento\" : 22,\r\n    \"dataDecreto\" : 61415276400000,\r\n    \"numeroDecretoPagamento\" : \"numero dec pag\",\r\n    \"tipoPagamento\" : \"tipo pag\",\r\n    \"importoInPagamento\" : 45,\r\n    \"notaDecreto\" : \"nota dec\"\r\n  }, {\r\n    \"progressivoPagamento\" : 22,\r\n    \"dataDecreto\" : 61415276400000,\r\n    \"numeroDecretoPagamento\" : \"numero dec pag\",\r\n    \"tipoPagamento\" : \"tipo pag\",\r\n    \"importoInPagamento\" : 45,\r\n    \"notaDecreto\" : \"nota dec\"\r\n  } ]\r\n}, {\r\n  \"ente\" : \"Roma\",\r\n  \"cup\" : \"ABCDE3593CXXE\",\r\n  \"decretoImpegno\" : \"decreto singolo\",\r\n  \"dataDecretoImpegno\" : 61415276400000,\r\n  \"importoImpegno\" : 56000,\r\n  \"finanziatoMiur\" : 343434,\r\n  \"importoPagato\" : 55656,\r\n  \"importoInPagamento\" : 9999,\r\n  \"details\" : [ {\r\n    \"progressivoPagamento\" : 22,\r\n    \"dataDecreto\" : 61415276400000,\r\n    \"numeroDecretoPagamento\" : \"numero dec pag\",\r\n    \"tipoPagamento\" : \"tipo pag\",\r\n    \"importoInPagamento\" : 45,\r\n    \"notaDecreto\" : \"nota dec\"\r\n  }, {\r\n    \"progressivoPagamento\" : 22,\r\n    \"dataDecreto\" : 61415276400000,\r\n    \"numeroDecretoPagamento\" : \"numero dec pag\",\r\n    \"tipoPagamento\" : \"tipo pag\",\r\n    \"importoInPagamento\" : 45,\r\n    \"notaDecreto\" : \"nota dec\"\r\n  } ]\r\n} ]"
```

After that, I parse this string to JSON: `str = JSON.parse(str)`.

Then, I pass the str to DataTable:

```
var oTable = $('#exampleTable').dataTable({
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "aaData": str,
...
```

But, I get an error:

> DataTables warning: table id=exampleTable - Requested unknown parameter 'ente' for row 0. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4

The strange thing happen when, before to parse the str string:

(1)I display it with `console.log(str);` in my web console.

(2)I copy the result of console.log into a js variable.

```
    var res = [ { //this JSON is exactly what I get from Ajax, the same I parsed..
      "ente" : "Roma",
      "cup" : "ABCDE3593CXXE",
      "decretoImpegno" : "decreto singolo",
      "dataDecretoImpegno" : 61415276400000,
      "importoImpegno" : 56000,
      "finanziatoMiur" : 343434,
      "importoPagato" : 55656,
      "importoInPagamento" : 9999,
      "details" : [ {
        "progressivoPagamento" : 22,
        "dataDecreto" : 61415276400000,
        "numeroDecretoPagamento" : "numero dec pag",
        "tipoPagamento" : "tipo pag",
        "importoInPagamento" : 45,
        "notaDecreto" : "nota dec"
      }],
      "importoDaPagare" : 277779
    }, {
      "ente" : "Roma",
      "cup" : "ABCDE3593CXXE",
      "decretoImpegno" : "decreto singolo",
      "dataDecretoImpegno" : 61415276400000,
      "importoImpegno" : 56000,
      "finanziatoMiur" : 343434,
      "importoPagato" : 55656,
      "importoInPagamento" : 9999,
      "details" : [ {
        "progressivoPagamento" : 22,
        "dataDecreto" : 61415276400000,
        "numeroDecretoPagamento" : "numero dec pag",
        "tipoPagamento" : "tipo pag",
        "importoInPagamento" : 45,
        "notaDecreto" : "nota dec"
      } ],
      "importoDaPagare" : 277779
    } ];
```

(3) I pass this variable to DataTable (without parse it) and works!!

```
var oTable = $('#exampleTable').dataTable({
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "aaData": res,
...
```

How it's possible?

**Datatable.js**

```
detailsTableHtml = $("#detailsTable").html();

    //Insert a 'details' column to the table
    var nCloneTh = document.createElement('th');
    var nCloneTd = document.createElement('td');
    nCloneTd.innerHTML = '<img src="http://i.imgur.com/SD7Dz.png">';
    nCloneTd.className = "center";

    $('#exampleTable thead tr').each(function () {
        this.insertBefore(nCloneTh, this.childNodes[0]);
    });

    $('#exampleTable tbody tr').each(function () {
        this.insertBefore(nCloneTd.cloneNode(true), this.childNodes[0]);
    });


    //Initialse DataTables, with no sorting on the 'details' column
    var oTable = $('#exampleTable').dataTable({
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "aaData": res,
        "bPaginate": true,
        "aoColumns": [
            {
               "mDataProp": null,
               "sClass": "control center",
               "sDefaultContent": '<img src="http://i.imgur.com/SD7Dz.png">'
            },
            { "mDataProp": "ente" },
            { "mDataProp": "cup" },
            { "mDataProp": "decretoImpegno" },
            { "mDataProp": "dataDecretoImpegno" },
            { "mDataProp": "importoImpegno" },
            { "mDataProp": "finanziatoMiur" },
            { "mDataProp": "importoPagato" },
            { "mDataProp": "importoInPagamento" }   
        ],
        "oLanguage": {
            "sInfo": "_TOTAL_ entries"
        },
        "aaSorting": [[1, 'asc']]
    });

    /* Add event listener for opening and closing details
    * Note that the indicator for showing which row is open is not controlled by DataTables,
    * rather it is done here
    */
    $('#exampleTable tbody td img').on('click', function () {
        var nTr = $(this).parents('tr')[0];
        var nTds = this;

        if (oTable.fnIsOpen(nTr)) {
            /* This row is already open - close it */
            this.src = "http://i.imgur.com/SD7Dz.png";
            oTable.fnClose(nTr);
        }
        else {
            /* Open this row */
            var rowIndex = oTable.fnGetPosition( $(nTds).closest('tr')[0] ); 
            var detailsRowData = res[rowIndex].details;

            this.src = "http://i.imgur.com/d4ICC.png";
            oTable.fnOpen(nTr, fnFormatDetails(iTableCounter, detailsTableHtml), 'detail');
            oInnerTable = $("#exampleTable_" + iTableCounter).dataTable({
                "bJQueryUI": true,
                "bFilter": true,
                "aaData": detailsRowData,
                "bSort" : true, // disables sorting
                "aoColumns": [
                { "mDataProp": "progressivoPagamento" },
                { "mDataProp": "dataDecreto" },
                { "mDataProp": "numeroDecretoPagamento" },
                { "mDataProp": "tipoPagamento" },
                { "mDataProp": "importoInPagamento" },
                { "mDataProp": "notaDecreto" }                  
            ],
                "bPaginate": true,
                "oLanguage": {
                    "sInfo": "_TOTAL_ entries"
                }/*,
                "fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull ) {
                  var imgLink = aData['pic']; 
                  var imgTag = '<img width="100px" src="' + imgLink + '"/>';
                  $('td:eq(0)', nRow).html(imgTag);  
                 return nRow;
                }*/
            });
            iTableCounter = iTableCounter + 1;
        }
    });
```

**SOLUTION:** I miss to add `dataType: 'json'` into the aJax call...

Comment: Do you use `columns.data` option in your initialization? Please show complete DataTables initialization code for clarity.

Comment: Does it work if you omit `str = JSON.parse(str)`? Then most likely `str` is already an object converted from JSON string and doesn't need to be parsed. Just use `"aaData": str` in you initialization code.

Comment: @Gyrocode.com, I already tried, but it's not work...

Comment: Something wrong with content of `str` variable, can you **exact** output of `console.log(str)` before you call `JSON.parse`?

Comment: Your code works fine then, see https://jsfiddle.net/5aub4s69/

Comment: I have done the same thing, but it's not work for me...

Comment: I use 1.10.3 version of dataTable.js.. Maybe if for that?

Comment: @Gyrocode.com, I solved the problem, I missed the dataType in the Ajax call.. Now, I have another question if you can help me. There is any way to format the import? If I have this import 23244 I would it was formatted in 23.244,00, for example.. It's possible?